# EFS CSI driver using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, kubernetes-helm, amazon-efs

I am attempting to install the EFS CSI driver using Helm via Terraform, but I'm encountering an issue related to specifying the repo URL and image tag/URI. Whenever I provide these values, I receive a "context deadline exceeded" error.

Here is a snippet of my Terraform code that deploys the Helm chart:

```
resource "helm_release" "test_aws_efs_controller" {
  name       = "aws-efs-csi-driver"
  repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-efs-csi-driver/"
  chart      = "aws-efs-csi-driver"
  namespace  = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment_name}-microservices"
  version    = "2.2.0"

  set {
    name  = "clusterName"
    value = var.test_ekscluster_id
  }

  # set {
  #   name  = "image.repository"
  #   value = "public.ecr.aws/efs-csi-driver/amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver:v1.6.0"
  # }


  # set {
  #   name  = "image.tag"
  #   value = "v2.4.8"
  # }

  set {
    name  = "controller.serviceAccount.create"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.serviceAccount.annotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = var.aws_efs_controller_role_arn
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.serviceAccount.name"
    value = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment_name}-efs-controller"
  }

  depends_on = [
    var.test_nodegroup,
    var.aws_efs_controller_role_attach
  ]

}
```

I have tried various combinations for the repository and version fields, as well as different values for image.repository, but I continue to encounter the "context deadline exceeded" error.

Can someone please provide guidance on the correct values to use for these fields when deploying the EFS CSI driver with Helm via Terraform? Additionally, if there are any specific Helm chart configurations that need to be set for this driver, please let me know.

Comment: Where is your EKS cluster located in, i.e., which region?

Comment: It is located in Mumbai region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver#deploy-the-driver) in the Helm chart GitHub repo:

> To specify an image repository, add the following argument. Replace the repository address with the cluster's [container image address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-ons-images.html).

The example the documentation shows is:

```
--set image.repository=602401143452.dkr.ecr.region-code.amazonaws.com/eks/aws-efs-csi-driver
```

Since the cluster is running in the Mumbai (`ap-south-1`) region, you need to fix the code to the following:

```
resource "helm_release" "test_aws_efs_controller" {
  name       = "aws-efs-csi-driver"
  repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-efs-csi-driver/"
  chart      = "aws-efs-csi-driver"
  namespace  = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment_name}-microservices"
  version    = "2.4.9"

  set {
    name  = "clusterName"
    value = var.test_ekscluster_id
  }

  set {
    name  = "image.repository"
    value = "602401143452.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/eks/aws-efs-csi-driver"
  }

  set {
      name  = "image.tag"
      value = "v1.6.0"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.serviceAccount.create"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.serviceAccount.annotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = var.aws_efs_controller_role_arn
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.serviceAccount.name"
    value = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment_name}-efs-controller"
  }

}
```

---

In order to find which Helm chart version to use, this command should be used:

```bash
helm search repo aws-efs-csi-driver
```

which will output:

```
NAME                                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
aws-efs-csi-driver/aws-efs-csi-driver   2.4.9           1.6.0       A Helm chart for AWS EFS CSI Driver
```

The `version` argument of the `helm_release` expects what is listed under the `CHART VERSION` column. The `APP VERSION` in this case matches what is listed in the GitHub documentation for [AWS EFS CSI driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver#ecr-image):

```
public.ecr.aws/efs-csi-driver/amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver:v1.6.0
```

Where the image tag (`v1.6.0`) corresponds to the app version. However, that might be the case for this particular chart, and not a rule for all the other charts.

Comment: After doing this, I'm getting these error statement Error: context deadline exceeded and this warning message:  Warning: Helm release "aws-efs-csi-driver" was created but has a failed status. Use the `helm` command to investigate the error, correct it, then run Terraform again.

Comment: Yeah, fixed the image repository, I forgot to add `eks/aws-efs-csi-driver`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. If possible can you tell me how did you came across version 2.4.9 and the image tag? I didn't found any useful document regarding this. 
If you have any can you send it here

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the answer.